# CSS margin: 0 auto messing up another DIV's alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

<
    my issue was when I did anything with the "BACK TO TOP" button it would mess up the "bottom" div. After I added the "back to top" button, it screws up the bottom div. I have tried to dabble with the "bottom" div itself, but, no luck. How will I be able to allow the bottom to be centered like it is supposed to be?

```css
.imagen {
padding-top:200px;
 display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 width: 350px;
 height:auto;
 }
 body {
 margin:0;
 }

 #menulist {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:900px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:100px;
 }
 
 .linkactive {
 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 1000;
 font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 190px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 }
 
 .link {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 1000;
 font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
 font-size: 30px;
    width: 190px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .link:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: grey;
 }
 .section1 {
 margin:0 auto;
 width:900px;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight: 1;
 }
 #reflection{

margin: 0 auto;
width:900px;
}



.bottom{
margin-top:100px;
width:100%;
height:200px;
background-color:#fffef9;
}

.section6{

margin: 0 auto;
width:900px;
}
#text6{
padding-top:100px;
font-weight: 1000;
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
font-size:15px;
color:black;
letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#btt{
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:100px;
margin: 0 auto;
width:900px;
}
 a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 1000;
 font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
 font-size: 30px;
    width: 190px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 }
 
 a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: grey;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Pen+Script" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Give+You+Glory" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molle:400i" rel="stylesheet">


<body>

 <img class=imagen src='closed.jpg' onmouseover="this.src='open.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='closed.jpg';" />

<div id="menubar">
     <ul id="menulist">
  
  
  <li class="link" onclick="reStyle(0)"><a href="Joseph Kwong resume.html">about</a></li>
  
         <li class="link" onclick="reStyle(1)"><a href="Joseph Kwong resume.1.html">portfolio</a></li>
         <li class="linkactive" onclick="reStyle(2)">reflection<li>
         <li class="link" onclick="reStyle(3)"><a href="Joseph Kwong resume.3.html">contact</a></li>
        
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="reflection"> 
   
</div>

<div id="btt">
<a  href="Joseph Kwong resume.1.html" >BACK TO TOP<a>
</div>

<div class=bottom>
<div class=section6>

<p id="text6">Copyright © 2018 Joseph Kwong - All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the expected result? If you'll have a 'Back to top' button then it needs to be as a fixed position

Answer (score 0):

You left off a `/` at the end of your `<a>` tag. Try adding a `/` and see if that fixes it.

```
<div id="btt">
<a  href="Joseph Kwong resume.1.html" >BACK TO TOP<a>
</div>
```